# Rotation by AffineTransform makes saved image empty

Tags: java, image-processing, rotation, save, affinetransform

Ok my problem is simple, after performing AffineTransform, my image is not saving properly (however it is drawn on JPanel properly!). It is really strange, so any hints are really appreciated...

Take a look on code:

```
    public BufferedImage performRotation(BufferedImage bi){

    if (angle!=180){
        at.translate(0.5*bi.getHeight(), 0.5*bi.getWidth());
        if(clockwise){
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle));
        }else{
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(-angle));
        }            
        at.translate(-0.5*bi.getWidth(), -0.5*bi.getHeight());
    }
    else if(angle==180){
        at.translate(0.5*bi.getWidth(), 0.5*bi.getHeight());
        at.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle));
        at.translate(-0.5*bi.getWidth(), -0.5*bi.getHeight());
    }

    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    BufferedImage bi2 = op.filter(bi, null);

    try {                  
    ImageIO.write(bi, "bmp", new File("BEFORE filterORIG.bmp"));
    ImageIO.write(bi2, "bmp", new File("AFTER filterNEW.bmp"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DrawingField.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

File BEFORE filterORIG is saved properly -> there is an image, but its pre-rotated.

File AFTER... is saved as blank file.

What is really interesting, is previously mentioned fact that this transformation is poperly shown on JPanel that i use as a display (i can observe effect of desired transformation)

Any help appreciated...

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the return is not the result of the transform, but a 'filtered' version (whatever that is). My guess is something like `new BufferedImage bi2(); op.filter(bi,bi2);` is what you want. But I don't know enough about it to write a complete answer.

Comment: YESS it worksss!! thx a lot! I was struggling with it since few hours! I am really grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Try writing `png` images, ie:

```
ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("BEFORE filterORIG.png"));
ImageIO.write(bi2, "png", new File("AFTER filterNEW.png"));
```

The resulting image (bi2) may have an aplha channel and `ImageIO` may not allow to encode images with aplha as `bmp`.

Alternatively, create a destination image with `TYPE_INT_RGB` color model and use it as a second argument in `filter()` method.